# GCP Snapshot create API failing through C++ code, but not through postman

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've been trying to make API calls to create snapshot of GCP disk through my code but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Failed to check snapshot status before creating GCPDisk swift-snapshot-gkeos-dkdwl-dynamic-pvc-1b13097f-7-1630579922. HTTP Error: GET request to the remote host failed [HTTP-Code: 404]: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "The resource 'projects/rw-migration-dev/global/snapshots/swift-snapshot-gkeos-dkdwl-dynamic-pvc-1b13097f-7-1630579922' was not found",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The resource 'projects/rw-migration-dev/global/snapshots/swift-snapshot-gkeos-dkdwl-dynamic-pvc-1b13097f-7-1630579922' was not found",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My program worked fine for a considerable amount of time, but now sometimes it gives errors.
I tried passing the same query through postman and it works fine. Some times it works fine through .

The main problem is with the snapshot creating API,
[https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{projectName}/zones/{diskLocation}/disks/{diskName}/createSnapshot](https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%7BprojectName%7D/zones/%7BdiskLocation%7D/disks/%7BdiskName%7D/createSnapshot)

This URL works fine on postman, after creation you can see the snapshot when you list them, but through code once this API is called it returns an OK 200, but no snapshot is created

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Your question does not include the code that generates the error. Do you have a race condition where you are checking before the resource is created? Your API link is broken. Typically an API call will return a handle to check status. I am not sure what your code is doing or the API your code is calling or how you are managing the returned results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use this operation:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/createSnapshot

Which is a long running operation, a 200 response indicates that the snapshot operation *started*, but it does **not** indicate that it has *finished*.

The documentation points to:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses#handling_api_responses

You may need to poll the operation until it completes before trying to use the snapshot.